# how do i fill the entries of this matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, loops

Given:

```
h_i=t_(i+1)-t_i for i=1,...,n-1 where n is a positive integer.
```

The matrix `Q` is an `n` by `(n-2)` matrix with entries `q_(i,j)` with `i=1,...,n` and `j=2,...n-1` given by:

```
q_(j-1,j)=1/h_(j-1)
q_(j,j)=-(1/h_(j-1)+1/h_j)
q_(j+1,j)=1/h_j
q_(i,j)=0 for |i-j|>=2
```

I want to get a matrix `Q`. How do i write a program for this matrix in R? Many thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I've figured out the subscripts correctly, I think this will do it:

```
n <- 100
t <- sort(runif(n))
h <- diff(t)
Q <- matrix(0,n,n-2)
Q[row(Q)==col(Q)-1] <- 1/h[1:(n-3)]
Q[row(Q)==col(Q)+1] <- 1/h[1:(n-2)]
diag(Q) <- c(NA,-1/h[1:(n-3)] - 1/h[2:(n-2)])
```